# Use the smallest width qualifier -Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

Android documentation [Use the Smallest-width Qualifier](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali) 
states:

```
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)

600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc)
```

meaning that screen widths with 660dp and higher are tablets like. But a phone with lets say only 5.5 inches and 1440x2960 570dpi doesnt mean that it is a tablet.

So how can you distinguish that difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But a phone with lets say only 5.5 inches and 1440x2960 570dpi doesnt mean that it is a tablet.

Correct.

> So how can you distinguish that difference?

Use the smallest-width qualifier.

1440 pixels at 570 dpi = 2.53 inches = 404dp. 404dp is less than 600dp, and so your proposed device would not use `-sw600dp` resources.

Comment: @CommonsWare-Lets say i have a 5 inch phone  with 720x1280  and 160 dpi = 720dp. But is not a tablet.

Comment: @Nick: It is not mathematically possible to have a device with those characteristics. 720 pixels at 160dpi = 4.5", for the shorter side. It is not possible to construct a rectangle with a 5" diagonal and a 4.5" short side.

Comment: Oh yeah my mistake. See this example: 1800x2960 480dpi = 600dp. Could you also explain apart from that, could i use the available width instead of smallest-width qualifier in your above answer? Thanks

Comment: @Nick: "See this example: 1800x2960 480dpi = 600dp" -- 1800 pixels at 480 dpi = 3.75 inches = 600dp. However, there are no phones with a smallest width of 3.75 inches. Larger phones might have a smallest width of around 3 inches. "could i use the available width instead of smallest-width qualifier in your above answer?" -- yes, though bear in mind that this varies by orientation. Portrait has a smaller available width than does landscape.

Comment: So to get this right... Phones specifications are made in a way that the 600 dp will always be the base for distinguishing tablets from phone

Comment: @Nick: No, because "tablet" and "phone" are marketing terms. Moreover, from a GUI design standpoint, worrying about labels like "tablet" and "phone" is pointless. Instead, worry about whether your UI looks OK at different window sizes, and choose a dividing line that makes sense. This is no different than what Web developers do, using CSS media queries. Moreover, with Android 7.0+ multi-window, the screen size of the device may have little to do with the size of your activity's window.

Comment: @CommonsWare-okk and thanks for your time. One more example tho. Lets say we have a device 1080x1920 320 dpi. We have 1080*160/320 = 540dp. But if you do the math, the device has ~7" inches. So it has a screen size for tablet but it will not use the -sw600dp resources. Right?

Comment: Correct. Marketing tends to sell based on diagonal length. Developers tend to build UIs based on width and height. The `600dp`-for-7"-tablets is a rough rule of thumb, nothing more.