# How to define width and height for an imageview for all screens?

Tags: java, android, dimensions, android-screen-support

I have an imageview with width 250dp and height 250dp, on a nexus 5 5.0 inch 1080x1920 xxhdpi is looks good, but when i change my emulator device to a bigger screen for example 6.0inch pixel 2 xl 1440x2880, 560 dpi it's really small.

I know i have to declare other dimensions in a dimens.xml file to support other screens and i'm using size qualifiers small, normal, large and xlarge but for some reason on some devices it doesn't look good.

What is the best way to define width/height for the imageview so it looks good on all screens?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you used dp and not px?  In dp, everything is the same physical size-  250x250dp is always 1.5626 inches by 1.5625 inches.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes i used dp, the size of the imageview itself is just not good on larger screens, 250x250dp on my 5.0 inch nexus emulator looks good in size, but on a larger phone it is smaller.

Comment: But if you used dp it isn't smaller. It's the same physical size. Which doesn't mean you may not want it to be bigger on a larger screen, but it isn't smaller. If it's smaller than you didn't use dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be having different density images (ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi) or svg image to look good in different density screens. In order to look good in different screen sizes (physical size) - you must have check in your layout in different screen preview available in preview of xml design. For easy creation of the preview screen you will find `orienation symbol` in preview screen click it -> you will have drop down in that click `Create Other` -> next you will get a dialog in that you must follow the naming convention as in the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes. For example : for small screen you will have to name it as `layout-small` you will get `activity_main.xml(small)` in that you can change the image view properties to look good in that screen.

Comment: So it's sufficient to only use the size qualifiers (small, normal, large, xlarge) ? I read something about smallest width qualifiers but don't understand it.

Comment: Yes you are correct - in order to support different physical sizes uses different smallest width qualifier (e.g :  -sw600dp). Please use preview in android-studio to check whether your design have met your need. Ref this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796453/10698239 in addition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so do i combine size and density qualifiers or only density?

Comment: If you want to support different density screen you must use different density images or svg. If you want to support different physical size device with required design you must implement the required XML files. Do both if you need both.

Comment: Ok i have made dimens files for size qualifiers for small, normal, large and xlarge but if i want to let's say for example make a density qualifier for sw320 sw480 sw600 and sw720, how does the device know which file to use?